Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine but could not find or invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant
I am experiencing issues with multiple Flutter plugins (OneSignal, Razorpay, FlutterToast, UrlLauncher, etc.) not being registered correctly. The errors indicate missing implementations for various methods. Notably, the application worked fine yesterday, but after restarting my device, I started encountering these issues.
Environment:

Flutter version: latest version

Kotlin version: '1.9.22'

Operating System: Windows 11


Error Log:

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method OneSignal#setLogLevel on channel OneSignal#debug)
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method OneSignal#initialize on channel OneSignal)
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method OneSignal#lifecycleInit on channel OneSignal#inAppMessages)
Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine but could not find or invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Razorpay#init on channel razorpay_flutter)
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Razorpay#close on channel razorpay_flutter)

MainActivity.kt:
Previous code:
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrantclass MainActivity : FlutterActivity()

Modified code:
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrantclass MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}

MainActivity.kt (for FlutterFragmentActivity):
Previous code:
package com.example.pursueimport io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrantclass MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {}

Modified code:
package com.example.pursueimport io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrantclass MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}

GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:
package io.flutter.plugins;import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.Log;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.spencerccf.app_settings.AppSettingsPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin app_settings, com.spencerccf.app_settings.AppSettingsPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin cloud_firestore, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.analytics.FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_analytics, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.analytics.FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_auth, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_core, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_messaging, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_local_notifications, com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.example.fluttershare.FlutterSharePlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_share, com.example.fluttershare.FlutterSharePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.FlutterToastPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin fluttertoast, io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.FlutterToastPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin google_sign_in_android, io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new in.juspay.hyper_sdk_flutter.HyperSdkFlutterPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin hypersdkflutter, in.juspay.hyper_sdk_flutter.HyperSdkFlutterPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.moengage.flutter.MoEngageFlutterPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin moengage_flutter_android, com.moengage.flutter.MoEngageFlutterPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.onesignal.flutter.OneSignalPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin onesignal_flutter, com.onesignal.flutter.OneSignalPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin path_provider_android, io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.razorpay.razorpay_flutter.RazorpayFlutterPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin razorpay_flutter, com.razorpay.razorpay_flutter.RazorpayFlutterPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithApplePlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin sign_in_with_apple, com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithApplePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin url_launcher_android, io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin", e);
    }
  }
}

AndroidManifest.xml file:
<manifest xmlns:android="`<`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`>`"
    xmlns:tools="`<`http://schemas.android.com/tools`>`"
    package="com.pursueit.pursue">    <application
        android:label="Pursue"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.CodelessDebugLogEnabled"
                android:value="true" />            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>



Steps taken:

I have verified that the GeneratedPluginRegistrant class is present and correctly implemented.

I have attempted to register the plugins within the manually configureFlutterEngine method in MainActivity.

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times.



InvocationTargetException (talk about it because it happens first and all other issues is just aftershock) is kinda "wrapper" exception around actual exception happened inside method called thorough reflection. Since Flutter's plugin registration is reflection based, exception happens somewhere inside it.
From stacktrace I can say the exception raises somewhere inside initialisation of firebase_messaging package, cause stack trace leads us to FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor.
It is hard to say what happens with certainty because I do not known version used in your app, your device etc... But I would start with update of firebase_messaging and clean reinstall of app

I've removed the firebase_messaging plugin but the error of MissingPluginException-No implementation found is showing again for all the plugins like razorpay_flutter, one_signal, fluttertoast. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project several times.
